# GAE/Go: /_ah/start returns 401

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Our GAE/Go application returns 401 response to /_ah/start like below.

[image]

app.yaml is this.

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1
application: (out app)
version: 777
threadsafe: true
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1  

handlers:

- url: /_ah/.*
  script: _go_app

- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
  login: required
  secure: always
```

Why we have this error? How can I fix this?
We know deleting `manual_scaling` can fix this error, but we would like to restrict the number of our instance.

Comment: You can't call /_ah/start yourself. The App Engine subsystem calls it, which is the reason you are getting `401` Unauthorized errors.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear I know GAE call /_ah/start. My question is why my app returns 401 error.